# Can't boot Windows after unsuccessful install of Ubuntu through USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

First of all, I am completely new to Ubuntu and not very knowledgeable with computers in general. Please forgive me for my explanation maybe being vague or word choice being incorrect.

I am using a Windows 8 and wanted to try Ubuntu by installing from a USB.
I used Unetbootin to install the files on an USB. After following the wizard and installing Ubuntu through the USB, I was told to reboot the system.
After that, I encountered two problems.

1) The Ubuntu install never seemed to have been successful. Even after the full install process, I only have the "try ubuntu" or "install ubuntu" options on the grub menu.

2) The bigger problem. I am unable to access Windows anymore, even if I change the booting order to my original HDD through the F2 option.

I have looked for solutions on the internet and have tried using Boot-Repair

I was able to navigate through Boot-Repair's instructions smoothly, however, the last message said "There was an error during the repair . . . you may now reboot your system," and neither of my problems have been solved.
The log of the repair is as follows: It would be great if you could take a look at it since it's my only way to concretely explain my situation.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8637867/

I also read about using a windows repair-cd or usb, but my laptop has no cd drive and I am unable to acquire usbs to fix my windows system as of now.

Will I need to reformat my windows system?

I would b very grateful to receive some help on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Looking at

```
Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     1,050,623     1,048,576 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2       1,050,624   233,445,375   232,394,752 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda3     233,445,376   250,068,991    16,623,616 Swap partition (Linux)
```

and

```
1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 0 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.
```

it seems that you completely wiped out Windows and installed Ubuntu on the whole hard drive. The only way to get Windows back is by reinstalling it using a DVD/USB.

If you remove USB drive and set HDD as first boot device it should boot Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking at is the Live Boot menu from your USB device.
I think you would se the regular grub menu, when you boot up, without the USB device in.

The Try Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu options are only available when booting a live media.

And according to your boot rescue there, you have used your entire disk for Ubuntu, effectively wiping your Windows install.